# Symfony 3 Inject Container in FormType

Tags: php, symfony

How to inject container on FormType in Symfony 3.0?

My services.yml file:

```
services:
    advertiser.form.report:
        class: App\AdvertiserBundle\Form\ReportType
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

In the action controller:

```
$report = $this->get( 'advertiser.form.report' );
$form = $this->createForm( $report );
```

I got this error:

> Expected argument of type "string", "App\AdvertiserBundle\Form\ReportType" given

Comment: Replace $report with 'ReportType::class'.  Not very intuitive but this will end up pulling the report type from the container.

Comment: By the way, you will need to tag your service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: That work perfectly! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use form factory instead.

In configuration:

```
services:
    advertiser.form.report:
        class:  'Symfony\Component\Form\Form'
        factory: ['@form.factory', 'create']
        arguments: [App\AdvertiserBundle\Form\ReportType, null, {container: '@service_container'}]
```

In your form add `container` to possible form options:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'container' => null,
        //The rest of options
    ]);
}
```

And use it as you want:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $container = $options['container'];
    //The rest of logic
}
```

In your controller, just use form:

```
$this->get('advertiser.form.report'); //It's a ready-to-use form, you don't need to call $this->createForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

As in comments, the fix is easy; you should only do:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ReportType::class);
```

Anyhow, I would highly discourage you from injecting the whole container in ANY kind of class. It's better to inject only the needed service.